# How to perform L2 Normalization for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, matrix

I need to normalize a set of feature vectors stored in training, validation and test matrices.

Doing L2-norm in a vector is quite easy, just divide each vector value by its norm.

However, how to do that in matrices in the context of machine learning? should I:

1. Divide each vector (each matrix line) by its norm? or should I divide all elements in the matrix by the matrix norm, considering all the matrix as one big vector?
2. Store the training matrix norm and use it to normalize the elements on the validation and testing matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L2 norm of a matrix (also called the Frobenius norm) is equivalent to the L2 norm of its vectorized form. So for a standard machine learning algorithm what you'd want to do is simply vectorize all your matrices and then normalize them as you normally would.

That said, most matrix-variate data is a matrix for a reason (which is to say, there is likely some structure in the ordering of rows and/or columns). If this is true, then you may want to consider a normalization approach that is more appropriate to the data that you have -- for example, you could normalize each entry individually, or each column, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I chose to normalize each value of each column of my matrix by the L2 norm of that column. For machine learning purposes, do you recommend me to save the vector of L2 norms of my training matrix and use it to normalize the validation and test matrices? I've heard that this is usually done for other normalizations, such as z-norm and min-max. Is that correct?

Comment: Normalizing usually means removing the mean and dividing by the standard deviation--what do you mean by 'normalize by the L2 norm?' But yes, the parameters you use to normalize your training data are also the ones you should use to normalize validation/test samples